# What is the problem of in_channel in initial operation of ConvLSTM by Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, lstm

I have some question about the ConvLSTM by Pytorch, just like this code:`class ConvLSTMCell(nn.Module):

```
def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, bias):
    """
    Initialize ConvLSTM cell.
    Parameters
    ----------
    in_channels: int 输入特征图的通道数
    out_channels: int 输出特征图的通道数
    kernel_size: (int, int) 卷积核的宽和高
    bias: bool 是否使用偏置
    """
    super().__init__()
    self.in_channels = in_channels
    self.out_channels = out_channels

    self.kernel_size = kernel_size # wsg: 此处 kernel_size 需设为列表
    self.padding = kernel_size[0] // 2, kernel_size[1] // 2
    # 需要强制进行padding以保证每次卷积后形状不发生变化
    # 在stride=1时，padding = kernel_size // 2
    # 如：卷积核为3×3则需要padding=1即可
    # 在下面的卷积操作中stride使用的是默认值1
    self.bias = bias
    self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=self.in_channels + self.out_channels,
                          out_channels=4 * self.out_channels,
                          kernel_size=self.kernel_size,
                          padding=self.padding,
                          bias=self.bias)
    # wsg:初始化输入通道，in+out vs. in+out*2？C_t-1 不算？因为是窥视结构？

def forward(self, input_tensor, last_state):
    """
    params
        input_tensor: 当前时刻的输入x_t, 形状为
                     [batch_size, in_channels, height, width]
        last_state: 上一时刻的状态c_{t-1}和h_{t-1}, 形状均为 
                    [batch_size, out_channels, height, width]
    return
    """
    
    h_last, c_last = last_state # 前一时刻
    combined_input = torch.cat([input_tensor, h_last], dim=1)
    # [batch_size, in_channels+out_channels, height, width]
    combined_conv = self.conv(combined_input)  
    # [batch_size, 4 * out_channels, height, width]
    # wsg：输入只有 x_t 与 h_(t-1)？没有 C_(t-1) 吗？
    cc_i, cc_f, cc_o, cc_g = torch.split(combined_conv,
                                         self.out_channels, dim=1)
    # 分割得到每个门对应的卷积计算结果，形状均为
    #   [batch_size, out_channels, height, width]
    i = torch.sigmoid(cc_i)
    f = torch.sigmoid(cc_f)
    o = torch.sigmoid(cc_o)
    g = torch.tanh(cc_g) 
    c_next = f * c_last + i * g  # [batch_size, out_channels, height, width]
    h_next = o * torch.tanh(c_next)  # [batch_size, out_channels, height, width]
    return h_next, c_next

def init_hidden(self, batch_size, image_size):
    height, width = image_size
    return (torch.zeros(batch_size, self.out_channels, height, width, device=self.conv.weight.device),
            torch.zeros(batch_size, self.out_channels, height, width, device=self.conv.weight.device))`
```

the `nn.Module(in_channel + out_channel` (in_channel is for X_t, out_channel is for H_(t-1) or C_(t-1))， whether is the dimension of input X_t and the hidden H_(t-1) ?
But in the ConvLSTM Methodology (Shi et al. 2015, Convolutional LSTM Network: A Machine Learning Approach for Precipitation Nowcasting), there should be three input, that is X_t, H_(t-1) and C_(t-1). So I think there should be in_channel + out_channel * 2.

Maybe because the C_(t-1) is the weephole structure so it is not be as an input?

Comment: Your code snippet is a bit out of context, you are showing a single conv block definition. Please provide some more details and reformulate your post. *whether is the dimension of input X_t and the hidden H_(t-1) ?* is not a question.

Comment: thank you, I have edit my question. this code about my question is 
self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=self.in_channels + 
                          self.out_channels,
                          out_channels=4 * self.out_channels,
                          kernel_size=self.kernel_size,
                          padding=self.padding,
                          bias=self.bias)

Comment: I have got it!. This is for the conventional operation between H_(t-1) and X_t. Because this conv is the first and is noting to C_(t-1), so there is no out_channels * 2 but just one out_channels.